# Почему лагает прокрутка сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, возможно вы видите какой то баг в коде или что такое, но сайт лагает при прокрутке, как будто подзависает в некоторых местах, подскажите что сделать что бы изменить это? http://cheap-shopping.mega-mind.info/beta/home/

Comment: Не похоже, что лагает. Похоже на рекламу сайта. ))

Comment: 8 просмотров, да огромная реклама XD Нет он серьезно лагает  !

Comment: Скажем так, не очень плавно прокрутка на сайте!

Comment: @arthru не увидел лагов, но проблема скорее всего из за фиксированного заднего фона. читай это https://habrahabr.ru/post/282079/

Comment: Тоже не заметил лагов на сайте. И согласен с комментатором выше - что скорее всего из-за бэкграунда и возможн, раз упоминулись скрипты...может скрипт отрабатывает каждое событие на прокрутку (один раз щёлкнул колёсиком, несколько событий произошло (если есть какой то обработчик скрола)) у вас там адская куча скриптов + ошибки из-за них в консоле... смотрите в консоль, правте, смотрите какие обработчики использует скролл... но первым делом bg.

Answer (score 1):

Прокрутка лагает из-за того, что на странице вызывается много перерисовок. Для устранения проблемы стоит через devtools смотреть, какие блоки переписываются и оптимизировать их рендеринг.